# Remix run: Route with dynamic ID is not working when used with layout?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I have the following

```
▾ app/
  ▸ api/
  ▸ components/
  ▾ routes/
    ▸ _landing/
    ▸ _landing._index/
    ▸ _landing.jobs/
    ▾ _landing.jobs.$id/    <============ doesn't work
        route.tsx
```

I'm trying to make a route for `/jobs/:id` with the "_landing" layout. However, in it's current state if I visit `/jobs/blah`, it just renders the `/jobs` components.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new `v2` flat routes convention, the way Remix determines the *parent layout* is based on the longest matching prefix.

In your case, `_landing.jobs.$id.tsx` sees there's a `_landing.jobs.tsx` file and uses that as the parent layout. To opt out of the layout, you need to add the `_` suffix: `_landing.jobs_.$id.tsx`. This says that `_landing.jobs` is NOT a layout.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/routes#nested-urls-without-layout-nesting